# Algorithm to find best order for items on pages with a fixed height

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, search-algorithms

I am looking for an algorithm to find the best order of items to fit on pages.
Consider the following case, we have a page with the *height = 300*
We have images with the following heights - *[150,200,100,150,300]*

So I want to find the best order for this images in order to fill the page.
For example:

**First page**: 150 - 150
**Second page**: 200 - 100
**Third page**: 300
**Fourth page**: 150

Are there any algorithms to solve this task?

Have tried to find algorithms but only have an idea to just solve it via several iterations over an array.

Comment: How do you evaluate a proposed order?  What metric do you use to determine which order is "best"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it might be the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).  If so, the problem is NP-complete, but there are many methods for heuristics, approximation algorithms, etc., which you can read about and apply in your setting.